# EJB3 Caching Instance Variables

Tags: variables, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, instance, stateless-session-bean

I've noticed some strange code on a project I am working on - its a SLSB EJB3, and it uses a private instance variable to maintain a cache of data (it even calls it dataCache or something), with a getter/setter. For EJB2 and bellow, this was a typical EJB antipattern - SLSBs are not meant to retain state in between invocations, theres no guarantee you'll see the same data on a subsequent invocation. One of my colleagues said maybe its ok in EJB3 (we don't have much EJB3 experience), but still, its a Stateless Session Bean - why is it trying to maintain state, this doesn't make sense.

Can anyone confirm if this is still a bad idea in EJB3 land, or if somehow it is ok?

Thanks if you can help, Justin

Answer (score 1):

In EJB 3.1 you'd do this cleanly by having a separate singleton bean (with the [`@Singleton`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/Singleton.html) annotation) and injecting via `@EJB` it into the session beans that need it.

Before EJB 3.1, there is no really clean way and you have to use some sort of hack.

Answer (score 0):

> For EJB2 and bellow, this was a typical EJB antipattern - SLSBs are not meant to retain state in between invocations, there's no guarantee you'll see the same data on a subsequent invocation.

This is true and this is somehow a smell (because often wrongly used: people tend to forget that there is no guarantee to get the same instance, that the container could remove some bean from the pool to free resources, that beans could be distributed across JVMs, etc).

> One of my colleagues said maybe its OK in EJB3 (we don't have much EJB3 experience), but still, its a Stateless Session Bean - why is it trying to maintain state, this doesn't make sense.

What was true with Stateless Session Beans (SLSB) in EJB 2.x is still true with EJB 3.0, SLSB are still SLSB, EJB 3.0 didn't redefine statelessness.

But if you use an instance variable to hold some **read-only** resource that is expensive to load (and make sure to load it if `null`), it should be ok.

#### Related questions

- [Stateless and Stateful Enterprise Java Beans](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2351220/70604)
- [Stateless session bean with instance variables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1628009/70604)
- [Static vs Instance members in Stateless EJBs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1558646/70604)
- [Why stateless session beans are single threaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29734/70604)

Comment: Thanks Pascal, that confirms what I suspected

Comment: "But if you use an instance variable to hold some read-only resource that is expensive to load (and make sure to load it if null), it should be ok."   Do not recommend this.  the value should be either injected or managed somewhere "not in the SLSB" because of all the caveats that come with the contract the SLSB provides (stateless, pooled, proxied, ad-hoc GC if the container deems appropriate, etc.).  load the value in a session context CDI bean (or similar context that maintains state) and inject it if need be.